# Nexpose: Stuck at login

Tags: login

I've install NexPose on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop following [these](https://nexpose.help.rapid7.com/docs/install) instructions. My 1st time launching NexPose went fine and I was able to launch, login and activate NexPose. However, after the 1st time, I'm now stuck at the login screen every time I try to use NexPose.

[image]

What I do every time:

1. In the terminal, run `sudo systemctl start nexposeconsole.service`
2. In the Firefox browser, go to `https://localhost:3780`
3. Wait for it to load
4. Enter my credentials and Press Enter or "LOG ON"
5. NexPose does nothing. Just stuck there.

Is this a problem with Ubuntu, Firefox or NexPose? How should I fix this?